# How to start the Morgan's Spiral quest chain?

Tags: guild-wars-2

There is a jump puzzle in Morgan's spiral, but it can only be activated while the tower is "in bloom". However, many risen party poopers seem to have for sole purpose the destruction of the tower, making the puzzle impossible to complete (in fact, impossible to start). There is a series of events, however, nearby which involves escorting someone to the tower, allowing him to heal it, and defending said tower against undead.

Due to the time of day at which I play, the tower is almost always destroyed when I get there. However, despite searching online and asking other players, I cannot seem to find out how to start the quest chain to heal the tower, hence my question.

- Who do I need to talk to in order to initiate this quest chain?
- Is there something specific that needs to happen in order to start the chain?

**Edit:** I should specify that I know the first event in the chain is called `Escort Brugh to Morgan's Spiral`, but what I don't know is how to initiate that quest or the conditions that need to be satisfied to initiate it.

Comment: It's worth noting that if people are inside already they can open the side door to let more players in. However you'll not get the award for completing the jumping puzzle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some dynamic events start up by themselves either periodically or when players are near, while others require a player to speak to an NPC to kick them off. In this case, I believe the event *should* start up by itself, but, since [it is bugged](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Talk:Brugh), the event can "get stuck" (Brugh just stands around and tells you to "stay on your guard" despite nothing happening) and you will not be able to restore the spiral to its "fixed" state.

[This GW2 Forum thread](https://forum-en.guildwars2.com/forum/support/bugs/Escort-Brugh-to-Morgan-s-Spiral-bugged) and [this one](https://forum-en.guildwars2.com/forum/support/bugs/Bugged-event-cutting-off-access-to-two-jps) seem to indicate that the problem has existed for quite a while. Despite a [note in the 2012-11-15 game update](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Game_updates/2012-11-15#Events) claiming that it has been fixed, that doesn't seem to be the case.

For what it's worth, it is still possible to climb up the spiral when it is in the "damaged" state - it's just a little harder and not so obvious to tell where you have to jump from the wilted leaves onto the rock, but it can be done. (I suspect you may not get the achievement, at least for the first jumping puzzle - my guess would be you can still go and complete the second jumping puzzle achievement, but I haven't confirmed this.)

Please also note that the comment in the first forum thread I linked to about being unable to get the skill point is incorrect - you don't have to complete the jumping puzzle for this, you just have to interact with the skill point at the bottom of the spiral to obtain [Morgan's Orchid](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Morgan's_Orchid_(item)), which you can do irrespective of the spiral's state. Consuming this orchid will give you the skill point.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the quest `Escort Brugh to Morgan's Spiral` initiated the quest chain  you seek.

http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Escort_Brugh_to_Morgan%27s_Spiral

Comment: Right, but how do you initiate that quest?